# Yellow sidebar on SU meta does not have coloured SU logo for Blog

Tags: discussion

***Update:***

You can no longer see this because the Podcast link is now there. It may come back in the future.

---

On the yellow sidebar on SU (the main site), this is what you see:

[image]

The Blog logo is the coloured logo (correctly, because it is on the main site) and the Featured on Meta logo is black and white (correctly, because it is on the meta site).

Rolling over this logo says "Super User".

---

On the yellow sidebar on SU (the meta site), this is what you see:

[image]

Rolling over this logo say "Meta Super User".

---

Does anybody think the meta's sidebar ***should*** have the coloured logo for the blog? It's a small thing, but it's noticeable...

Comment: I now understand what you mean. I don't think it matters, but I do see what you're talking about

Comment: @CanadianLuke But, there's no harm in changing it to the coloured logo, is there? (I'm a bit picky in these type of things :)

Comment: Actually, when you hover over that icon, it says "Meta Super User".

Comment: @LéoLam Good point, that should say "Super User", as it is on the main site.